# Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging 6 is not logging

Tags: c#

I've searching quite a lot of posts but none of them is helping,  I used EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.6.0.1304.0, as we know that we need to set logwriter.
Below is what I did.

```
var config = new LoggingConfiguration();
var flatTextFormatter = new FlatFileTraceListener("flatfilelog.txt", "--start here--", "--end here--");
config.AddLogSource("Level1", SourceLevels.All, true, flatTextFormatter);
var defaultWriter = new LogWriter(config);
Logger.SetLogWriter(defaultWriter);
Log("test", Category.Debug, Priority.Low);
```

and if I don't use **SetLogWriter**, just call `defaultWriter.Write("test")`; then it's fine.

Anybody knows why?

Thanks

Comment: And what is the problem? Is nothing happening, or are you getting an error message of some sort?

Comment: thanks, there was no error at all, I set breakpoint at Log function, it can run , just not writing the file.